# Beginner JSON/JQuery Issue

Tags: json, jquery

I'm building a Django application and am trying to integrate JSON, but I'm having some issues. Django is generating the feed, which is here: http://www.crowdpoint.org/session/1/activeCheck

Here is the JQuery I'm using to pull down the feed. The problem is that neither of the alerts fire, so I don't think the code is working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.crowdpoint.org/session/1/activeCheck', function(data) {
    alert('Test 1')
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    alert('Test 2');
    });
});
```

Comment: Are there any messages in the error console? What do you see in the "Net" / "Network" tab of your debugging tool of choice (Firebug, Chrome / IE Dev tools, etc)?

Comment: try fixing your missing brackets and semicolons first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) violation. If the JS and the JSON resource are on the same domain, you should be using a local path not a fully qualified URI. For example...

instead of this

```
$.getJSON('http://www.crowdpoint.org/session/1/activeCheck' ...
```

use this

```
$.getJSON('/session/1/activeCheck' ...
```

My guess is you're accessing the originating URL on `http://crowdpoint.org/` or something else that isn't exactly `http://www.crowdpoint.org/`

If the script and resource are on different domains, you'll need to use JSONP which would involve some changes to the way your service responds.

Answer (score -2):

you miss `;` in the third line....

Comment: Semicolons are not required in JS